# GCP AI Platform: The script _name_ is installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, setuptools, google-ai-platform

I am trying to push python files to the Google AI Platform (unified). For the dependencies I am using setuptools:

```
%%writefile custom/setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['scikit-learn', 'pandas', 'numpy>=1.17', 'transformers', 'tensorboard']

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My training application package.'
)
```

Getting this error for all the packages within `REQUIRED PACKAGES`.

```
"pathname": "run_module.py",
"levelname": "ERROR",
"message": "  WARNING: The script tensorboard is installed in '/root/.local/bin' which is not on PATH."
```

[image]

The `pathname` `run_module.py` is coming from Google Cloud. I do not have a file named like that. Am I supposed to change the file name of my training task to run_module.py and it will work?

Answer (score 1):

We have followed the [Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-custom-job) (Formerly called as AI Platform Unified) documentation and [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/training-tuning-caip#0) and run some training jobs. We could see the same error/warning messages in the Stackdriver logs but the training jobs are running successfully.

After contacting the ML team responsible for this product, they have confirmed that there should be no impact on the training jobs due to these error/warning messages showing up in stackdriver logs. Let us know if you see any failure in the final outcome of your training jobs.